# Get React root url path

Tags: reactjs, url, path, react-router, location

I'm creating a react app with create-react-app and react-router.
I would like to get the root URL path of my react app as it can be served in a different location :

- In production: example.com/interface/
- In local: localhost/

The links to the different pages are not affected by this difference because react-router handle to-location according to the react root path.
Actually, my images are stored in the public path, therefore, I can access it in the base locations: `/<page>`

```
<img src={images/example.png}>
```

but if I'm in a subpage or just if the URL ended with a "/" like `/<page>/`

```
<img src={images/example.png}>
```

won't work because browser searches the image at `/<page>/images/example.png` instead of `/images/example.png`.
Moreover, if I set the image src to `/images/example.png` It works only on localhost but not in production because in production, browser searches the image at `example.com/images/example.png` instead of `example.com/interface/images/example.png`

That's why I need to get the react root URL path. It allows me to get "/" in localhost and "/interface/" in production for example

Thank you for helping

Comment: Try it with `<base href="http://localhost/" />` in your `<head>` section.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the solution: Webpack gets the react root URL in the env variable `PUBLIC_URL`

The solution is to change the image src :

```
<img src=`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/example.png`
```

it works in production, in development and every other context.
Thank you for your help

Comment: No offense, but while this may work, it completely contradicts the concept of the webpack asset pipeline and will cause you problems at some point.
Instead of trying to find workaround for non-existing problems I would strongly encourage you to do it the right way, especially if you are new to React. ;)

Answer (score 7):

This can be done setting the `homepage` property in `package.json`.
When building the project, you see a message explaining it:

> The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root. To
>   override this, specify the homepage in your package.json. For example,
>   add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
>
> `"homepage": "http://myname.github.io/myapp"`

See the documentation: [Deployment: Building for relative paths](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)

If you do this, it should also work on production when it works on your local dev environment.

In your case, set `"homepage": "https://example.com/interface/"` to make it work on production. You don't need additional code for it.

Keep in mind that you may have to import the image paths properly, so that the logic is handled by webpack.
You shouldn't have real web paths in your components, just import things from the paths you have in your dev environment and the magic works.

```
import example from 'images/example.png';
[...]
<img src={example} />
```

See [Adding Images, Fonts and Styles](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) and [Using the public folder: When to use the public folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#when-to-use-the-public-folder)

Comment: By importing the image with Webpack, it can not be stored in the public folder?
Have I to store the image in src folder?

Comment: Yes. If this image is related to the component's logic (e.g. the `Logo` component has a logo image to show, the `ProfilePicture` component has a default image to show if now image was set by the user) it makes sense to store that image alongside with the component.  
Depending on the size of that imported image webpack will either include it as base64 to the JavaScript (makes sense for small icons to save requests) or deploy it with a unique ID to /static/media/.  
  
App images are assets and when your app is updated, you want to make sure the user sees the new image. Webpack handles this.

Comment: @Aurélien for more details see here [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to be able to set a different root path based on your development environment vs your production environment.

Fortunately, create-react-app allows you to create environment variables, using a `.env` file.

You will need one of these files on your local as well as production. Please note you MUST NOT add these files to version control as they usually contain secret keys, and even if they do not it is good practice.

Once you've created a `.env` file, you will need to prefix all of your environment variables with `REACT_APP<environment variable>`, so in this case, `REACT_APP_ROOT_PATH`.
You will then need to set it as follows;

`REACT_APP_ROOT_PATH=localhost/` for your local environment, and

`REACT_APP_ROOT_PATH=example.com/interface/` for your local environment.

For more advanced uses of this feature, here is some documentation: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#expanding-environment-variables-in-env

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Aurélien [Here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration) you see a description of `PUBLIC_URL`. It's not what you want.
`REACT_APP_ROOT_PATH` is not even documented there. You should follow [Deployment: Building for relative pahts](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: @Frébo The reason it is not documented is because it is a custom variable which is defined by the user. As long as you prefix `env` variables with `REACT_APP_`, create-react-app will pick them up and you are able to use them in your code. This is documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)